# Why do some Linux system calls have two man pages?

Tags: linux, manpage

Example:

http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket
http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket

In what way they are different?

Comment: I guess in short: BSD sockets (portable interface accross platforms that support them) vs Linux specific parts about sockets. I think the man pages explains this somewhat. `man 2 socket` being the BSD socket part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`socket(2)` provides documentation for the `socket()` system call; `socket(7)` describes how to use sockets (in general) on Linux.

`man man` gives you an overview of sections:

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
       man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

This list is more or less (though not quite) "universal" across UNIX systems, and the sections you're interested in most of the time. [Wikipedia has more documentation on man sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) as used in various UNIX systems.

There are many "duplicate" manpages, for example `crontab(1)` describes `/sbin/crontab`, and `crontab(5)` describes the `crontab` file format.

You can configure which section `man` uses if you don't explicitly add a section with the `MANSECT` environment variable; this defaults to `1 n l 8 3 0 2 5 4 9 6 7` on Linux.

For an introduction to each section, look at `man <n> intro` (ie. `man 7 intro`).

**Bonus tip**:
`apropos` is your friend:

```
$ apropos crontab
anacrontab (5)       - configuration file for Anacron
crontab (1)          - maintains crontab files for individual users
crontab (1p)         - schedule periodic background work
crontab (5)          - files used to schedule the execution of programs
```

Answer (score 1):

Man pages are mostly split into different sections numbered from 1-8.

Man 2 is for system calls. Man 7 is for Miscellaneous

```
 1      User Commands
 2      System Calls
 3      C Library Functions
 4      Devices and Special Files
 5      File Formats and Conventions
 6      Games et. Al.
 7      Miscellanea
 8      System Administration tools and Deamons
```

The link given below gives some info.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page